# Laravel Conditionally join tables based on specified class

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have three tables `customers`, `organizations` and `contacts`. Table `customers` table has columns `customer_class` (the class indicates table use `Organization`, `Contact`) and `customer_id` (corresponds to column `id` in either `organizations` or `contacts`).

So what I did was

```
$interactions = DB::table('sales_interactions')
->join('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'sales_interactions.customer_id')
->join('organizations', function($join)
{
    $join->on('customers.customer_id', '=', 'organizations.id')
        ->where('customers.customer_class', '=', 'Organization');       
})
->join('contacts', function($join)
{
    $join->on('customers.customer_id', '=', 'contacts.id')
        ->where('customers.customer_class', '=', 'Contact');       
})

->select([
    'organizations.title as customer',
    'contacts.name as customer',
    'sales_interactions.id',
    'sales_interactions.created_at',
    'sales_interactions.title',
    'status',
    'deadline',
    'value',
]);
```

It worked when I joined organizations only. But joining contacts returns zero results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a union query:

```
    $contactsQuery = DB::table('sales_interactions')
        ->join('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'sales_interactions.customer_id')
        ->join('contacts', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('customers.customer_id', '=', 'contacts.id')
                ->where('customers.customer_class', '=', 'Contact');
        })
        ->select([
            'contacts.name as customer',
            'sales_interactions.id',
            'sales_interactions.created_at',
            'sales_interactions.title',
            'status',
            'deadline',
            'value',
        ]);

    $interactions = DB::table('sales_interactions')
        ->join('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'sales_interactions.customer_id')
        ->join('organizations', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('customers.customer_id', '=', 'organizations.id')
                ->where('customers.customer_class', '=', 'Organization');
        })
        ->select([
            'organizations.title as customer',
            'sales_interactions.id',
            'sales_interactions.created_at',
            'sales_interactions.title',
            'status',
            'deadline',
            'value',
        ])
        ->union($contactsQuery)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Yeah, my problem is that I'm alway looking for complex ways to do stuff :) I was trying to work out something like `JOIN ((SELECT organizations.title AS customer FROM organizations where customers.customer_class = 'Organization' ) UNION (SELECT contacts.name AS customer FROM customers where customers.customer_class = 'Contact' ))`, but your's should work just fine and that's all that matters. Thanks!!!

Comment: Followup - I'm feeding a combined query into `Datatables::of($interactions)...`, when it tries to query all columns I get error `1054 Unknown column 'customer' in 'where clause'`

Comment: What is: `Datatables::of` ? Is it same bundle or what?

Comment: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables - it takes query prepares data for bootstrap datatables. Solved by renaming `organizations.title` to `organizations.name`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Polimorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) in laravel doc. I recommend to use laravel orm, becouse it is very good and easy. This what You are looking for can be made simple query.